# jQuery .change() is not working

Tags: jquery

In my html structure, I have plus, minus and an input field. When there is any change in my input field, I want to alert 'change occured'. So, when I change the value in my input box by typing or using the up or down arrows then it is giving me an alert. But I have written some code to change the value of input field when I click on the anchor tags with class plus or minus. So, the value is changing when I use the anchor tags but the change function is not being triggered. And hence not getting any alert. So, can anyone please let me know why change is not working here.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="quantity">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus">-</a>
    <input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="2" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text" size="4">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev("input");
    var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1;
    text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1);
});

$(".minus").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).next("input");

    if(text.val() > 0){
      var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1;
      text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1);  
    }   
});
```

**jQuery to detect change of input:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {

         alert('change occurred');
    });
});
```

**What I have tried**

I have already tried: .trigger('change') and also used keyup and input but nothing helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hemal_301080/fL29vgug/5/)**

Change your code as follow. You need to `trigger()` a `.change()` event.

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).prev("input");
    var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1;
    text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1);
    text.trigger("change");
});

$(".minus").click(function() {
    var text = $(this).next("input");

    if(text.val() > 0){
      var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1;
      text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1);    
      }
      text.trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Check fiddle, its working.You might be missing something else on your side.

Comment: That works good in the demos. but may be having some problem on my live website. can you please give a look at the product add to cart section here: http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/shop/

Comment: The value is increasing but if you notice, I am not getting an alert which I have set on change.

Comment: I have set an alert message on change function. I am not getting the alert. But if you type a value then you will get an alert.

Comment: Can you check on your side if `text` is `undefined`

Comment: I could not find click event to `.plus`

Comment: And text is defined. The click event is in main.js. Link: 

http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/wp-content/themes/masonbaker/js/main.js

Comment: Move `$(document).on( 'change'` code to your js file.

Comment: Ok , when I moved it to the main.js file, now the onchange is working. thanks. but i want it in my functions.php file for my wordpress setup. so can you suggest why it is not working if I have it in my functions.php file

Comment: As I said, the same code did not work in functions.php file but after you said when I did copy it into main.js, the script is working

Comment: I mean to say if you place in js file, wordpress setup will work also

Comment: I have to call that jquery script inside a php function. So, I need it in my php file. well thanks for your help, I will try to call it through another js function.

Answer (score 2):

The `change` event is not fired when the element value is updated programmatically. In that case you need to trigger the event manually:

```
$(".plus").click(function() {
    var $text = $(this).prev("input");
    var value = parseInt($text.val(), 10) + 1;
    $text.val(value).change();
});

$(".minus").click(function() {
    var $text = $(this).next("input");
    var value = parseInt($text.val(), 10) - 1;
    $text.val(Math.max(0, value)).change();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/6bqxtz4m/)

Note that it's considered better practice to use `val()` when working with `input` types, over setting the `attr()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but it is not working in my case.

Comment: Why is that? As you can see from the demo it should be working fine. If you can actually provide some detail, such as an error, I can offer some help.

Comment: That works good in the demos. but may be having some problem on my live website. can you please give a look at the product add to cart section here: http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/shop/

Comment: Assuming you mean the -/+ to change the quantity input field, then it appears to be working fine (Chrome 48 on OSX)

Comment: If you will notice, on using the plus and minus button to add or remove an item, the numbers are changing but I am not getting the alert which means the change is not being triggered.

Comment: I have set an alert message on change function. I am not getting the alert. But if you type a value then you will get an alert.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

Start observing 'input' event instead of 'change'.

```
jQuery('#some_text_box').on('input', function() {
// do your stuff
});
```

**OR**

```
jQuery('#some_text_box').on('input propertychange paste', function() {
// do your stuff
});
```